# Why does ns-resolve after :refer :all not find my symbol?

Tags: clojure

If I begin a program with

```
(ns dailyprogrammer.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [dailyprogrammer.other :refer :all]))
```

and then later on attempt to resolve a function `hello` which is defined inside `other` using `resolve` or `ns-resolve` like so:

```
(resolve (symbol "hello"))
(ns-resolve *ns* (symbol "hello"))
```

I get nil returned. But I can simply call

```
(hello)
```

which will work. Why can't I use either resolve function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ns-resolve` does not look up symbols visible in `*ns*`, it looks up symbols that are defined in `*ns*`. `:refer :all` makes all symbols from the other ns visible in your definitions, it does not move or replicate their vars into your ns.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way of searching what is visible then? I can only think of doing something like `(ns-resolve ('namespace1 'namespace2...) (symbol "hello"))` where the list of namespaces contains the ones I imported?

Comment: there are `ns-aliases` to see aliased namespaces, `ns-interns` to see interned mappings, or `ns-map` to see all mappings

Comment: To follow up, I was trying to provide a command line interface to run a bunch of functions I'd written in a few different namespaces.
My end solution was to grab namespaces with `all-ns` and then `filter` them looking for `.startsWith` my project name, and then attempting to find the function with `ns-resolve`.